# Very Beginner Problem in Python While Loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Why this While loop is not breaking or stopping

I have added some output screenshot

```
term = 0
i = 13
while True:
    print i > 1
    print "i = ",i
    if i == 1:
        term += 1
        break
    if i%2 == 0:
        i = i / 2
        term += 1
    if i%2 != 0:
        i = i * 3 + 1
        term += 1
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCrU0.png)

I also tried This way too

```
term = 1
i = 13
while i > 1:
    print i > 1
    if i%2 == 0:
        i = i / 2
        term += 1
    if i%2 != 0:
        i = i * 3 + 1
        term += 1
```

Comment: It's not breaking or stopping because `i` oscillates between 2 and 4 infinitely based on how you've encoded the math for the next `i` so the stopping condition is unreachable. What is it supposed to do? Is this supposed to run [Collatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)?

Comment: mama, see the first one I use break in  first if block

Comment: @mama What do you mean? There is a `break` statement in the first one, and the second has a loop condition.

Comment: ggorlen, It suppose to stop when i is 1

Comment: rid, It i becomes 1, then it still pass through loop

Comment: @rid This program is testing the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) and if coded correctly will eventually reach 1.

Comment: You appear to be using Python 2 (based on the use of a `print` statement). As a beginner, you should be learning Python 3 instead.

Comment: you can play with it and move it around to learn how it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `elif` to make the cases mutually exclusive. You don't want multiple `if` statements to execute in the same loop iteration.

```
if i%2 == 0:
    i = i / 2
    term += 1
elif i%2 != 0:
    i = i * 3 + 1
    term += 1
```

Or just make it `else` since the second condition is redundant.

```
if i%2 == 0:
    i = i / 2
    term += 1
else:
    i = i * 3 + 1
    term += 1
```

---

The reason it oscillates between `2` and `4` as written is because `2` causes both `if` statements to run. `2` is even so the first one runs and halves `i`, making it `1`. Now it's odd and the second one triggers, turning `1` into `4`.

```
if i%2 == 0:
    i = i / 2       # 2 --> 1
    term += 1
if i%2 != 0:
    i = i * 3 + 1   # 1 --> 4
    term += 1
```

The next iteration `4` becomes `2`.

```
if i%2 == 0:
    i = i / 2       # 4 --> 2
    term += 1
```

These two iterations repeat over and over in an endless cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your `i` is 2. It is divisible by 2, so `if i % 2 == 0` fires, and `i` becomes 1. And the code continues to execute, so now we are at `if i % 2 != 0` line, and this condition is **also true**, because you just modified `i` and it's now 1. So `i` becomes 4.

Your modified second attempt, which prevents the second condition from being checked if the first one succeeds, is below:

```
term = 1
i = 13
while i > 1:
    print(i > 1)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        i = i / 2
        term += 1
    elif i % 2 != 0:
        i = i * 3 + 1
        term += 1
```

Also notice that you actually don't need to check the second condition, as it is definitely true if the first one is not, so `elif ...` line can be replaced just with `else:`

You can also use `continue` keyword to stop the rest of the loop from executing if the first condition is true:

```
term = 1
i = 13
while i > 1:
    print(i > 1)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        i = i / 2
        term += 1
        continue
    if i % 2 != 0:
        i = i * 3 + 1
        term += 1
```

Your first attempt has exactly the same problem; fixing it I leave as an exercise for the reader :)

P.S. **do not learn Python 2**

Comment: It's no more. https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
if i%2 == 0:
    i = i / 2
    term += 1
if i%2 != 0:
    i = i * 3 + 1
    term += 1
```

The problem is that, if `i % 2 == 0` is `true`, it will remain true until `i = 1`. Once `i = 1`, `i % 2 != 0` executes and makes `i = 4`.